# A FAULT? -> Free Webhost doesn't allow to install Drupal modules due to 128MB PHP memory limit even though PHPInfo says there is 256MB available?

Tags: hosting

I tried to install OpenAtrium on hostinger. It has a 265MB PHP memory limit (seen via PHP Info) but before the installation it showed a warning that it only has a 128MB memory limit which should be increased to 196MB. I have then tried to increase the memory via htacess to 512MB.

In the middle of the installation it sopped with an AJAX error concerning database tables and that the server closed own due to heavy server load. When I try to visit the page I get even this error (in addition)

PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'u301805396_db.taxonomy_vocabulary' doesn't exist: SELECT name, machine_name, vid FROM {taxonomy_vocabulary}; Array ( ) in taxonomy_vocabulary_get_names() (line 991 of /home/u301805396/public_html/modules/taxonomy/taxonomy.module).

The server doesn't have any site installed, it is empty (no files in public_html) and I just insert the files to install OpenAtrium immediately.

How I can configure this to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are describing is also discussed as an [Open Atrium issue](https://drupal.org/node/2206223). I was not able to work around it neither by altering `memory_limit` nor `max_execution_time`. I guess we have to wait for a fix to come out.